# How to dismiss and present the same modal view controller right after?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to make it seem as if it was a *reset* button.

It would take me to my mainviewcontroller screen and then come right back.

```
 MainViewController.m 
 MainViewController.h
 MainViewController.xib 
 ViewController.xib
 ViewController.m
 ViewController.h
```

I do not understand how I am supposed to do this.....

```
 - (IBAction)newGame:(id)sender {
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];     
      ViewController *screen = [[ViewController alloc] inittWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
      screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
      [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
 }
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it not possible to reset the state and reload the view in `ViewController` itself?

Comment: I'm not quite sure....I thought it could but I am being thrown errors....

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas of how to force dismiss->present the same modal after i clock on a button? basically Intended to use this for a reset button.

Answer (score 0):

Do that without animation, as following.

```
- (IBAction)newGame:(id)sender {
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];     
      ViewController *screen = [[ViewController alloc] inittWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
      screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
      [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:NO];
 }
```

Comment: I am getting an error of this sort now:

receiver type 'viewcontroller' for instance message does not declare a method with selector


for the following line

 ViewController *screen = [[ViewController alloc] inittWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];